# Check whether the differential form is correct

Tags: differential-forms

I have the following differential form
$$
\omega = \left( 2x \sin(y) + \alpha \frac{y+1}{\left(x-1\right)^2 +\left(y+1\right)^2}\right)dx + \left( \beta x^2 \cos(y) - \alpha \frac{x-1}{\left(x-1\right)^2 +\left(y+1\right)^2}\right)dx
$$
defined in $\mathbb{R}-\left\lbrace \left( 1,-1 \right) \right\rbrace $ and I have to check for which values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ it's closed and exact.
In order to verify closure I check equality with cross partial derivatives and it holds if $\beta = 1$ and $\forall \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. My problem is to find the value for which it's exact. I set
$$
U(x,y)= \int \omega_1 dx
$$
but I am not able to solve the integral. There is a easy way?

Comment: Stokes' theorem tells us that if $\omega=d\alpha$ that $\int_{\gamma} \omega=0$ for any closed curve $\gamma$ lying in the domain. We can exclude values of $\alpha$ by calculating $\int_{\gamma} \omega$ for some clever choice of $\gamma$. Try to find a $\gamma$ which simplifies the integral.

Comment: You have a typo in the expression for $\omega$. The second $dx$ should be $dy$. Looking at the terms with $\alpha$ as a coefficient, does this remind you of a simpler differential form with which you have some experience (say, in the text or lecture)?